# View Problems in Sculpt Mode

Tags: 3d-view

I have big view problems when i am in sculpt mode.
When i'm very close to the object i'm sculpting the view movements around it they get incredibly slow and the shifts are very short.
Someone know why that happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your mesh may be too dense and it's affecting you computers performance.

Comment: Yes. probably is that. There is a solution for it?